# Pycharm completion not working

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

I am using 2.7.3, registered with a key and everything. I am using Python 2.7.2 that came with my mac, my poor old mac. 
Code completion and Intention Actions are not showing up. 
I have not touched either one of those settings since installation.
It may be unrelated but completion on eclipse didn't work either.
How do I get these things working again?

Again, I don't know if this is related but when I tried to upgrade some packages through Pycharm | Settings | Project Interpreter I got this error I don't know if its related.

> Upgrade packages failed.
>
> The following command was executed:
>
> /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/packaging_tool.py install
>   --build-dir /private/var/folders/2m/chhqrrdn6698hyx3mt1gtcg00000gp/T/pycharm-packaging4157205818815644068.tmp
>   -U Twisted
>
> The error output of the command:
>
> Storing complete log in /Users/lego90511/Library/Logs/pip.log (1)

This is my Python Interpreter, the log was a bit much to put here.

[image]

Comment: Invalidate didn't work? What does it do? And how can I see if an interpreter is configured correctly or not? I used what Pycharm suggested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out there is a power save feature in the file menu. I had it turned on.

Comment: You can also do `Ctrl+Space` to bring up completion, hit `Ctrl+Space` one more time to bring up a longer list of completions. I've noticed maybe an hour or two of battery savings when Power Save mode is on.